# Given the distribution of a random variable $R$, who do you get a uniform random variable $U$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

Let us say you have a random variable $R$. How would one generate a uniform random variable $U$, with the maximum possible entropy (or infinite entropy, if $R$ has such)? (For simplicity, you may assume that $R$'s sample space is a subset of the real numbers.)

Note: $U$ is essentially gotten by applying a function to $R$. I believe what I am seeking is called a "randomness extractor", specifically one that preserves entropy, and works based a probability distribution.

Comment: And then how are $R$ and $U$ related? I think I'm missing some part of the question.

Comment: Randomness extractors are an entire area of study; I don't think you can just answer such a broad question. Usually in computer science one would assume that R and U are over bitstrings of a certain length, and the answer might depend on for instance the "min entropy" of R. Googling "randomness extractors" turns up some surveys.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an idea, assuming that you *don't* know anything about the distribution of $R$.

Let $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(B_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be samples of $R$, i.e. i.i.d. random variables with the distribution of $R$, and set $$
  C_i = \begin{cases}
    -1 & \text{if $A_i < B_i$,} \\
    1 & \text{if $A_i > B_i$,} \\
    0 & \text{if $A_i = B_i$.} \
  \end{cases}
$$
Then let $D_i$ be the $i$-th value of $C_i$ which isn't zero.

By construction, the $C_i$ are mutually independent, and so are thus the $D_i$. By symmetry, $P(C_i = -1) = P(C_i = 1)$, so the $D_i$ are uniformy distributed on $\{-1,1\}$. You can then use the $D_i$ to produce uniformy distributed values on larger probability spaces.

Comment: Is it entropy preserving? (It would have to be the joint entrophies of A and B)

Comment: @PyRulez Depends on how exactly you define that. $D_i$ has entropy 1. $R$ might have a larger entropy. But you can always combine multiple $D_i$ into some $F_i$ with higher entropy - but then you'll use more samples of $R$ to generate on $F_i$.

Comment: The point is you don't get unlimited samples. Ideally you are just applying a function to $R$.

Comment: @PyRulez I'm pretty certain you need to make *some* assumptions about $R$ then, at least of you want that function to be computable.